# Kernel sometimes quit after second evaluation of ListVectorPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

In Mathematica 10.01 Linux x386 execution of the expression

```
spin1 = Table[{{Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}, 0.3 {-Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π, π/6.}];    
spin1a = ListVectorPlot[spin1, VectorPoints -> All, 
  VectorScale -> 0.093, 
  VectorStyle -> {{Black, AbsoluteThickness[1], Arrowheads[0.02]}}, 
  Frame -> False]
```

and then

```
spin2 = Table[{1.2 {Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}, 0.3 {Cos[ϕ], -Sin[ϕ]}}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π, π/6.}];
spin2a = ListVectorPlot[spin2, VectorPoints -> All, 
  VectorStyle -> {{Black, AbsoluteThickness[1], Arrowheads[0.04]}}, 
  Frame -> False]
```

causes kernel quit.

Comment: Have you tried the latest Mathematica Version? 10.0.2 has fixed many bugs

Comment: In 10.0.2 under Windows 7 running the first block of code is sufficient to crash the Kernel.

Comment: Could someone check this on version 9 and/or 10.0.0?  I'd like to label this post appropriately.

Comment: reporting it internally

Comment: @rcollyer Reduced example: `ListVectorPlot[{{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard interesting. On current sources, the reduced example behaves slightly differently. Although, I reliably get different behaviors depending on what is turned on/off.

Comment: @rcollyer I actually get output from that form but it still crashes the kernel.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks. I see that, too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: crashes with 10.0.0, 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 on Windows but works with 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 on Windows for me. For 10.0.1 there are additional error messages...

Comment: @Albert Thanks; annotated.

Comment: Both blocks cause my kernel to crash (10.0.2 / Win7x64 Enterprise) after 1 to 3 executions (varies seemingly at random).  Once or twice I got repeated messages and a graphics error... Graphics`Mesh`GeometryPlot::invplotreg: -- Message text not found -- ({Line[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}]}) - tool tip says "Graphics`Glyphs`GlyphDataFunction is not a Graphics primative or directive".

Answer (score 2):

On 10.4.1, it is fixed. Here's a screen shot of the second plot.

[image]